# Add custom address attribute to checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.3, address

I create custom address attribute, same as suggested here:
https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/

But when I place an order there is error occurs:

```
Property "Example" does not have accessor method "getExample" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface".
```

I know that this accessor must be in generated/code folder but it's empty there, I don't understand why it's not creating after I run di:compile. All other modules creating well.

This code must create it as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="example" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Can you help, please?